# Java: 2d array columns and rows

Tags: java

Thank you for taking the time to read,

I have a 2d matrix of booleans and im trying to change each of the border values to false. I have this working for the top and left-most borders but cant seem to figure out a working code for the bottom and right-most, any help would be appreciated, these are the codes for the upper and left-most:

// Changes border values to false

```
    for (int row = 0; row <matrix.length; row++) {
        int col = 0;
        matrix[row][col] = false;
    }

    for (int col = 0; col <matrix.length; col++) {
        int row = 0;
        matrix[row][col] = false;
    }
```

Comment: Square matrix? Homework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the row and col values the last values instead of zero;

for the last column:

```
for (int row = 0; row <matrix.length; row++) {
    int col = matrix[0].length-1;
    matrix[row][col] = false;
}
```

and last row:

```
for (int col = 0; col <matrix[0].length; col++) { 
    int row = matrix.length-1;
    matrix[row][col] = false;
}
```

Or better aproach to avoid creating new instances of `col`s and `row`s inside the loops;

```
for (int row = 0; row <matrix.length; row++) {
    matrix[row][matrix[0].length-1] = false;
}
for (int col = 0; col <matrix[0].length; col++) { 
    matrix[row][matrix.length-1] = false;
}
```

For col, the last value must be the length of a row, so I write `matrix[0].length` it might be any other suitable number too instead of 0, but out of bounds.

Comment: Avoid useless col and row instanciations inside the loops. Do it once outside.

Comment: You are right, it was just to make him understand with his own code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the easiest way I can think of is to just set `row` to the max value of rows through the loop (looks to be `matrix.length - 1` each time) as well. So, for example:

```
for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
    matrix[row][0] = false;
    matrix[row][matrix.length - 1] = false;
}
```

and do the same for your columns.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I very much appreciate such a quick reply

Comment: No problem, though @Yasin beat me to it. I think mine is a more efficient way of doing it (since you are doing both at the same time, and not create extra variables) but both are correct.

Comment: @Justin, you should choose an answer at least :)

Comment: oop sorry, first time ever using this site

Answer (score 0):

Or something like that;

```
 for(int c=0;c<matrix.length;c++){
              System.out.println("");
              for(int r=0;r<matrix[0].length;r++){
                if(c==0||r==0||c==matrix.length-1||r==matrix[0].length-1){
                    matrix[c][r] = false;
                }else{
                    matrix[c][r] = true;
                }
                System.out.print(" " + matrix[c][r]);
              }
          }
```